# Overlapping shortcut keys in Manjaro

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, manjaro

I have set the windows key to open the start menu and many different combinations with the windows key for different things such as win+T for opening terminal, win+E for opening file explorer. The issue is that whenever I use windows key for other such combination, the start menu always gets open.

For example: win+T opens terminal and start menu, win+E opens file explorer and start menu again simultaneously.

How to remove this?

Edit: I don't want to change the shortcut keys, I know how to do that. I just don't want the **key1 [+key2]** individual shortcuts to execute when I'm pressing **key1+key2+key3**

Comment: which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: XFCE currently, but I'm planning to switch to GNOME. So if possible, could you tell for both? @DonaldLWilson

Answer (score 2):

**Keyboard Shortcuts in XFCE**
In your panel, Applications -> Settings -> Keyboard.
Open the Application Shortcuts Tab.

[image: XFCE Keyboard Shortcut]

Look for the the Super(Windows) + T key combination.
You can *double click* to **edit** it to something else or browse through to see if there are any duplicates.
Also make sure your holding down on the windows key while your simultaneously pushing the **T**.

For **Gnome** or others
Go to **Settings**.

[image: Settings]

Click on **Devices** located at the bottom of the Settings app.

[image: Devices]

click on **Keyboard**.

[image: Keyboard]

The right pane displays all the keyboard shortcuts that exist in your system.

Double-click on the **Home folder** then press the Super key (Windows key) and E together. You should see it getting assigned immediately. Click **Set** and close the settings app.

[image]

That should take care of it.

Other useful resources:
  [X keyboard extension](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension)
  [Xorg/Keyboard configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration)
  [Extra keyboard keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys)

Comment: In windows, when you press win+E, it opens just the file explorer and not the start menu, right??? I want the same thing here, I don't want the start menu to pop up everytime I open file explorer or use win+R, win+TAB, etc.

Comment: What happens if you remove the keyboard shortcut  assigned to just the Win key, does this remove the problem? Not sure why your start menu would be opening along with all the other shortcuts?

Comment: Try and reassign the XFCE menu to another key; Try and use the “menu” key and see if that helps. https://forum.manjaro.org/t/shortcuts-with-win-button-super/8800/4

Comment: If I change the shortcut key, then it's fine. But I don't want to. It's annoying to close the start menu everytime I open a terminal or file explorer.

Comment: Tried reassigning as well, didn't work. Changing to menu key is fine, but I wanna solve the issue, not workaround it. @DonaldLWilson

Comment: I read the link. It's sad though that it doesn't support this :(

Comment: Might try this https://github.com/alols/xcape this may help your situation

Comment: execute this command from the terminal and look to see if there is anything conflicting   $ xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -lv

Comment: The xcape isn't for Arch-linux I guess, as they have only mentioned Debian based and Fedora based systems. Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: sudo pacman -S xcape

Comment: also read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension there maybe something within this wiki that you may find useful

Comment: There was no conflict in the shortcut output shown